# Как защититься от чрезмерной "пробивки" адресов через обработчик ajax запросов?

Tags: xss, ajax, безопасность, token, форма

Есть форма, где одно из первых полей сразу после заполнения `.on('blur')` прозрачно пробивается через БД сайта — зарегистрирован уже такой, или нет? В зависимости от результата, прячется или показывается часть полей ниже.

Злодеи могут такой механизм задолбать массовыми запросами, в результате чего типа получат инфу, которой у них быть не должно — отн. того, кто на сайте есть, а кого нет.

Как пока делаю: в сессии храню кол-во запросов. Если больше N — далее не обрабатываю, все ответы негативны. Понятно, что можно сессию сбросить, через прокси заходить, через Тор. Но, наверное, от полномасштабной пробивки это как-то защитит.

Как хочется делать: что-то типа защиты форм, где всякий раз генерится уникальный токен, который можно использовать только раз.

**Вопрос:** как «правильно» защититься от совсем уж наглой и массовой пробивки данных через обработчик ajax запросов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход с хранением количества запросов для определенных IP адресов как правило защищает неплохо, да и что-либо другое придумать тут крайне сложно. 
Можно лишь сменить уровень на котором проходит фильтрация и перенести эту задачу непосредственно на веб сервер.

Если используете IIS, то есть специальный модуль: [Dynamic IP Restrictions module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/548/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions/).

Думаю есть аналоги для Apache

Comment: Большой офис, все выходят в нет с одного IP с моей т.з. Не блокировать же их всех после того как N чел по разу зарегились.

Потом, сайт большой, там не только эта регистрация живёт, страницы-то они пускай смотрят, хоть по 100к раз одну и ту же : )

Comment: Это уже тонкости настройки, вешаете фильтр только там, где он необходим. Также блокировка проходит не только по количеству запросов, но и по интервалами между ними. 
Конечно, блокировать сразу по IP не очень хороший вариант в случае с Вашим примером. 
Можно попробовать сделать связку сессия + IP. То есть первоначально блок идет для конкретной сессии, при росте запросов с одинакового IP и росте блоков сессий просто закрываем IP

Comment: Логично! Пошёл читать про похожие модули для `nginx`. Не спешу принимать Ваш ответ, подожду ещё прозрений.

Comment: Кстати, в дополнение к модулю для IIS: проблема доступа нескольких человек с одного IP там решена. Есть специальный режим "Proxy". Почитать об этом можно здесь: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vyunev/archive/2012/03/12/iis-8-ip.aspx